# CodeIgniter unit test framework fails to assert on strings containing periods

Tags: php, codeigniter, unit-testing

I have the following in CodeIgniter:

```
class Foo extends CI_Controller
{  
    public function __construct()
    {  
         parent::__construct();  
         $this->load->library('unit_test');
    }  
    public function test() 
    {  
        $ip = '1.2.3.4';  
        $this->unit->run($ip,'1.2.3.4');
    }  
}
```

The above test fails.  Why does the assert equals fail in this unit test?  If I pass in a String with no `periods .` it asserts correctly.

**UPDATE**

> i have just tested it and the result is a pass

```
echo $this->unit->report();
```

returns a status of failed.

Comment: i have just tested it and the result is a `pass`.

Comment: I agree to Khawer, I just tested it as well and it passed. How do know it failed?

Comment: @KaranAshar Ran it with the report function and it failed in the generated html page that `report` gives.